# WooCommerce change price when adding product to order in admin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We have customers who have different discount percentages. This is all programmed and working on the front end when adding products to the cart, but if using the back end order admin to add a new product I can't seem to find a way to calculate the new product price based on the user's discount. Is there a way to change the price in the woocommerce_new_order_item hook when adding a product to an existing order in the  order admin?

Here's what I have so far:

```
function action_woocommerce_new_order_item( $item_id, $item, $order_id ) { 
    // only run this from the WP admin section
    if ( !is_admin() )
        return;

    $item_type = $item->get_type();

    // return if this is not a product (i.e. fee, tax, etc.)
    if ( $item_type != 'line_item' )
        return;

    $product = wc_get_product( $item->get_product_id() );

    if ( !$product )
        return;

    $current_price = $product->get_price();
    $quantity = $item->get_quantity();

    // here I get the order's user's discount percentage and calculate the new discounted price
    // custom function
    $discounted_price = get_discounted_price( $current_price, $users_discount );

    $new_price = ( !empty($discounted_price) ) ? $discounted_price : $current_price;

    // this doesn't work
    $item->set_price( $new_price );

    // and this doesn't work
    $product->set_price( $new_price );

    // this appears to work but I'm not sure if this the best way to accomplish this
    $item->set_total( $price * $quantity );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order_item', 'action_woocommerce_new_order_item', 10, 3 );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: This action 'woocommerce_new_order_item' is done AFTER the order item is saved, i.e. you should use it in read only mode.

Comment: Is there another, more suitable hook available?

I discovered that I can use these methods on the $item object in the function above: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html

Comment: I am wrong! There are two locations that this action is done only the last is done after the order item is saved.

Comment: I investigated the code in the second location which I did not know about and don't think that code is normally used so you are calling the action in Abstract_WC_Order_Item_Type_Data_Store::create() which would make the order item read-only.

Comment: This method seems to work but I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this:
`$item->set_total( $new_price * $quantity );`

Comment: Then I really don't understand because any changes to the order item would only change the object in memory but not in the database. So my analysis must be wrong - please ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for adding item meta and changing the item price in the order admin screen:

```
function action_woocommerce_new_order_item( $item_id, $item, $order_id ) { 
    // only run this from the WP admin section
    if ( !is_admin() )
        return;

    $item_type = $item->get_type();

    // return if this is not a product (i.e. fee, tax, etc.)
    if ( $item_type != 'line_item' )
            return;

    $product = wc_get_product( $item->get_product_id() );

    if ( !$product )
            return;

    $current_price = $product->get_price();
    $size = $product->get_attribute('size');

    // add custom item meta to order
    if ( $size ) {
            wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Size', $size , false );
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $order_user = $order->get_user();
    $order_user_id = $order->get_user_id();

    // get this order's user's discount %
    $users_discount = get_user_meta( $order_user_id, 'discount', true );
    $users_discount = ( $users_discount > 0 ) ? $users_discount : 0;

    // calculate the discounted price based on the user's discount (custom function)
    $discounted_price = get_discounted_price( $current_price, $users_discount );

    $quantity = $item->get_quantity();
    $new_price = ( !empty($discounted_price) ) ? $discounted_price : $current_price;

    $item->set_total( $new_price * $quantity );
}; 
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order_item', 'action_woocommerce_new_order_item', 10, 3 );
```